# What does the suffix '-fare' mean?

Tags: word-meaning, suffixes

I am wondering what the suffix *-fare* means.

I've seen a few words that possibly have this suffix, but I couldn't find a thing in common among them.

There are some words:

*- warfare

- airfare

- fanfare*

Since *fare* is the money for a ticket in a vehicle, *airfare* probably means the fare we pay for an aircraft ticket. This logic can't be applied to *warfare*, which is the act of war, and *fanfare*, which is a piece of music.

So, we can't say that the suffix *-fare* relates to the noun, can we?

Comment: First you should check the origin of these words to see if it really is a suffix. In the case of [*fanfare*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fanfare), is isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While these three words all end in *-fare*, they actually all differ in their construction.

*Warfare* is the only one which uses *-fare* as a suffix. The *-fare* suffix [comes from the Middle English *fare*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warfare), meaning passage or journey. Thus, the combination of *war* and *-fare* implies a meaning along the lines of "the passage of war", which roughly lines up with the current definition.

*Airfare*, meanwhile, I would argue, is not the word *air* with the suffix *-fare*, but rather the word *fare* with the prefix *air-*. This is because we are using *air-* to describe what type of *fare* is being discussed, similarly to how *airplane* distinguishes air-planes from, say, *hydroplanes*.

*Fanfare*, as user3169 pointed out in their comment, [comes from the French word *fanfare*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fanfare), so it doesn't have the same construction as *warfare*.